# Move the Cancel button away from the Save button when editing a post

Tags: feature-request, edits

[image]

The new style of the cancel button causes it to be almost directly adjacent to the save button. This is a usability issue because it causes an increased rate of false clicks. Cancelling is almost never what is intended. 95% of clicks in that area are for saving.

Users also might unintentionally save when they meant to cancel.

Please move the button a bit to the right.

Comment: *Cancelling is almost never what is intended. 95% of clicks in that area are for saving.* Hrm. Source?

Comment: Is this actually a problem? I literally never mis-clicked there, before.

Comment: @Cerbrus because the feature is new. Previously, the cancel link was small and spatially separated.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi are you trying to suggest that the number is wildly off?

Comment: We have a _"Are you sure you want to cancel?"_ popup, any way.

Comment: @boot, I am trying to suggest we don't know where that number comes from, as well as the *Cancelling is almost never what is intended* assertion. Is it your personal opinion?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, that is my estimate for the rate based on personal experience. Seems accurate enough.

Comment: userscript to fix the issue: `$('.cancel-edit').on('mouseover',function(e){$(this).css('margin-left',parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'),10)+e.clientX-$(this).offset().left+50)});`